# How long would it take Mustafa to do the job alone?

Tags: problem-solving

> Murat and Mustafa can do a job together in fifteen days. After they
>   have worked together for five days, Mustafa leaves the job. Murat
>   completes the job in sixteen days. How long would it take Mustafa to
>   do the job alone?

The answer is 40 days but I want the steps to solve this.

Comment: Without making too many assumptions we can say that it would take between 16 and infinite days.  Why do you think 40 days is the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\;x,y\;$ be the amount of days it takes to Murat, Mustafa respectively to complete the job alone. We're given that

$$15\left(\frac1x+\frac1y\right)=1$$

so that after 5 days they worked together they did one third of the job, and it then took Murat sixteen days to complete the two thirds that were still left:

$$\frac13+\frac{16}x=1\iff\frac x{16}=\frac32\implies x=24$$ and then

$$15\left(\frac1{24}+\frac1y\right)=1\implies\frac{15}y=\frac38\implies y=40$$

Answer (score 4):

The classical way of solving this would be to find the *speeds* by which they both work (for convenience, in units of full jobs per day). Let's say Murat works at speed $v_1$ and Mustafa works at speed $v_2$. Then the fact that they finish in $15$ days if they cooperate means that $v_1 + v_2 = \frac1{15}$.

If they work together for five days, then a third of the work is done. That means Murat does two thirds of a job in $16$ days, or symbolically, that
$$
v_1 = \frac{2/3}{16} = \frac1{24}
$$
Now you should be able to do the rest.

Comment: (+1) for giving an explanation without giving away every single aspect of the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Let $M$ be the fraction of the job that Murat can finish in one day.  Let $m$ be the fraction of the job that Mustafa can finish in one day. Then the statement that they can finish the job together in 15 days is:
$$M+m = \frac{1}{15}$$

After $5$ days then have finished
$$5(M+m) = \frac{5}{15} = \frac13$$
a third of the job.
Then we are told that for the remaining $\frac23$,

$$ 16M = \frac23 \implies M = \frac{2}{48} = \frac{1}{24} $$

So
$$
\frac{1}{24} + m = \frac{1}{15}\\
m = \frac{1}{15}-\frac{1}{24} = \frac{24-15}{24\cdot 15}=\frac{9}{360} = \frac{1}{40}
$$

So Mustapha finshes  $\frac{1}{40}$ each day.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the rate of work/day of Murat and $y$ the rate of work/day of Mustafa, and $w$ the unknown amount of work, then you can model the given information as:
$$
15 (x + y) = w \\
5(x+y) + 16 x = w
$$
The final equation is
$$
d \, y = w
$$
where $d$ is the sought for number of days.

These are three equations with three unknowns $d$, $x$, $y$ and an unkown workload $w$, which itself does not matter (except it should not be zero).

Substracting the second from the first equation gives
$$
10 (x+y) - 16 x = 0 \iff \\
10 y = 6 x \iff \\
y = (3/5) x
$$
and using this in the first one:
$$
w = 15 x + 15 (3/5) x = 24 x \iff \\
x = w / 24
$$
Which leads to
$$
y = (3/5) (w/24) = (1/40) w
$$
Then using the last equation
$$
d (1/40) w = w \iff \\
d = 40
$$